# Al parecer el metodo .getText(); no existe

Tags: java, color, rgba

estoy haciendo un programa muy pequeño para practicar el RGB, entonces decidi que si el usuario elije X numero en el CheckBox, entonces el contenedor (panel) se cambiaria a ese color, lo que pasa es esto:

Para poder poner un Color, se necesita poner en numero, ejemplo:

```
Color cl = new Color(255,70,10);
```

Asi que mi idea era obtener el numero que se elijio en el checkbox, para luego pasarlo a Int, y ahi, poder cambiar el color del panel, esto es lo que hice:

```
if(c.getSource() == bt1){

      R.getText(cb1);
      G.getText(cb2);  
      B.getText(cb3);

      Red = Integer.parseInt(R);
      Green = Integer.parseInt(G);
      Blue = Integer.parseInt(B);

      cl = new Color(Red, Green, Blue);

      jpanel.setBackground(cl);
  
    }
  }
```

Y cuando se presione el boton, se cambia el contenedor, el panel, pero el error que me aparece es lo siguiente

**
"Error: cannot find simbol

Symbol: method getText(JComboBox);
Location: variable G of type String"
**

soy nuevo en esto, y decidi aprender en java, pero no entiendo, porque segun yo, el .getText se podia utilizar tanto en variables numericas, como en variables de texto, si me pueden ayudar, seria genial, gracias!

Comment: Si puedes sube todo el programa ya que aqui no se ve bien que es cada variable.

Comment: El error es claro: estás llamando el método `getText()` sobre la variable `G` cuyo tipo es `String`, por lo que dicho método no existe.